# vCenter Converter 4.3 GPT disks or Converting from GTP to MBR

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, physical-to-virtual, vmware-converter

I have a physical 2008 R2 server with a GPT OS volume. I am trying to get the server converted to ESXi.

I understand that vCenter Converter will not convert/detect GPT Disks.

The question is, does anyone know how I can get my system on to MBR disks. I have tried turning off UEFI and repairing windows, but that isnt working. 
I have also tried doing a repair from a bare metal windows system backup, but it wont restore unless its uefi/gpt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I normally hate just linking to existing documentation for this kind of question the author of '[GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html)' has documented how to do this [HERE](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) under the section "Converting from GPT to MBR" and deserves to be directly attributed.

Answer (score 0):

Acronis have a product called disk director which can convert Mbr to Gpt and vise versa